# None of my validators are working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation

I have a field on a form where the user is allowed to enter a number between 0 and 5000

I have tried 3 different approaches but for all three of them when I enter a number greater than 5000, my form submission is accepted, which is not supposed to happen:

approach 1:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ControlToValidate="price" runat="server" ID ="inrange" 
                     ErrorMessage="Must not exceed 5k" 
                     OnServerValidate="lessThan5k">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

with this code in the codebehind

```
protected void lessThan5k(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
  if (Convert.ToInt32(price.Value) < 5000)
  {
    e.IsValid = true;
  }
  else
  {
    e.IsValid = false;
  }
}
```

approach 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var listen = document.getElementById("price");

  listen.addEventListener("input", function () {
    var value = new parseInt(price.Value);
    if (value > 5000) {
      price.setCustomValidity("must not exceed 5000");
    } else {
      price.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  });
</script>
```

and last but not least approach 3:

What's the right way to restrict a form field's numerical range?

Comment: Why don't you write up some javascript or jquery and check if the value is > 5000?  That way the form hasnt even had a chance to hit the server?  Alternatively can't you use a validator?

Comment: @JonH Approach 2 appears to be JavaScript.        jsmith - The "input" event only appears to be valid in HTML5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) could that be a factor?

Comment: Add an alert to the validation function to output the value of the comparison in the if, that way you will see if it compares correctly and more importantly if the code runs at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx). Drag it from the toolbox and drop it in the design of your page.

Set the following properties:

- ControlToValidate--> your TextBox Id
- Type --> Integer (so that it's treated as integer)
- MinimumValue --> 0
- MaximumValue --> 5000

If you won't the form to be posted even if the value doesn't pass the validation, then set `EnableClientScript = false`, so that it's posted and validate only on server side.

Remember that you also need to use a `RequiredFieldValidator` if you don't want to allow empty entries.

Comment: I tried adding the rangevalidator but now it's making my submit button completely unresponsive. the validator message now shows up but I can't submit anymore.

Comment: You won't be able to submit if the validation doesn't pass. If the user replaces a bad value with a good one, then it will let him submit it.

Comment: Actually, that's EXACTLY the point of the RangeValidator...you can't submit if the data is invalid.  If you still want to submit, you need to set `EnableClientScript="false"` on the `RangeValidator` and it'll take the submission and perform the validation server-side as a `PostBack`.  All this option will do is kick the results back to the client with the message displayed (and previous values except password stored if `ViewState` is active).

Comment: What I mean is that even if my input is correct, I can't submit. The button is unresponsive.

Comment: Have you added some code to your button? Have you tried adding a new button to your form and checking if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `RangeValidator` or any other validator controls built into ASP.NET.  This is the easiest way, as it works cross-browser.  Simply set the `MinimumValue`, `MaximumValue`, `Type`, and `Text` to appropriate values; you can even allow client-side validation using the `EnableClientScript` property.

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="inrange"
    ControlToValidate="price"
    MinimumValue="0"
    MaximumValue="5000"
    Type="Integer"
    EnableClientScript="true"
    Text="Must not exceed 5k"
    runat="server"/>
```

Alternatively, look at hooking the click event on the form submit button and perform client-side checking of the value, then canceling the click if the value isn't valid.  You'll still need to perform server-side validation of the value, though, because you cannot guarantee that users will have JavaScript enabled on their machine (which means they'd be able to submit invalid data).

```
function validatePrice(e){
    var value = new parseInt(price.Value);
    if (value > 5000) {
      price.setCustomValidity("must not exceed 5000");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      price.setCustomValidity("");
    }
};

if (window.addEventListener){
    document.getElementById("price").addEventListener("click", validatePrice);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
    document.getElementById("price").attachEvent("click", validatePrice);
}
```

Your original JavaScript code hooks the "input", when it should be hooking the "click" event.  Also, you need to know that that code doesn't work on anything below IE9...for those, you'd need to use `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener`.

A purely HTML5 method (which isn't necessarily cross-browser) is to set attributes on the input element itself.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="5000" step="0.01" placeholder="Price" />
```

This'll tell compatible browsers to perform browser-side validation before allowing the form to be submitted.  Chrome supports all those attributes, Firefox supports most of those I listed, but IE doesn't support them very well.

Answer (score 0):

Which event are you hooking into?

input is probably not the right one.

Either hook into the blur or chanced events on the field or the submit event on the form.

I do not think your current code executes at all.

Answer (score 0):

agree with saluce!

to check on server side if page is valid, the button's click event should look something like this:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            lblResponse.Text = "Page successfully submitted!";
        }
    }
```